# How would I get an HTML file to display from the bottom by default

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I am developing a test platform, for some modem hardware, in python, and am using the `logging` class to produce several test logs. Normally the logs are text files and each time a log entry is written an extra line is added to the end of appropriate log file.

I have used a Filter to write a log file in HTML format, such there is a header at the beginning of the file (giving a Title and defining a few CSS Styles), but the main document is NOT encased in a set of `<body>` `</body>` tags because the log facility only has the ability to add to the end of the file.

Because of the nature of the log, I cannot use a `#bottom` tag to identify the end of the HTML log file. Since the file can get quite long. and I would like to force the browser to display the end of the file by default.

This is an example of a "Verdict" test log ...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>InProgress: 130226_01_Nick_An_Example_Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
    <style>
    body
    {
    font-size:75%;
    font-family:verdana,arial,'sans serif';
    background-color:#FFFFF0;
    color:#000080;
    margin-left:20px;
    }
    #pass {margin-left:30px; color:darkgreen;}
    #fail {margin-left:30px; color:darkred;}
    #testIter {margin-left:30px;}
    #iterResult  {margin-left:50px;}
    #testResult  {margin-left:10px;}
    #testResPass {margin-left:10px; color:darkgreen;}
    #testResFail {margin-left:10px; color:darkred;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <p>******************************************************************************************************
    <p>Python Test Automation - myDUT : SmokeTst_PwrOn_ATCmd --> General Smoke Tests - Power On, AT Response
    <p>Testcase start: - 02/18/14 07:16:13
    <p>******************************************************************************************************
    <p>&nbsp
    <p>******************************************************************
    <p>*****  tcID: SmokeTst_PwrOn_ATCmd  -  ueID: myDUT            *****
    <p>******************************************************************
    <p>Test Case start: 02/18/14 07:16:48
    <p>*** Iteration 1  - 02/18/14 07:16:58 ***
    <p id="testIter">Test_PowerOn: 1 : UE Board(s) are alive and well ... 
    <p id="testIter">Iteration 1: PowerOn Test Successful
    <p id="testIter">RouterConfiguration (1) : Router configured and responding to AT Commands ... 
    <p id="testIter">Iteration 1: Router Setup Test Successful
    <p id="pass">Iteration 1: PASS
    <p id="testResult">Test Case finish: 02/18/14 07:20:09
    <p id="testResult">Test Case time: 00:2 min :00
    <p id="testResPass">TC overall result: *** PASS ***
    <p id="testResult">Number of iterations: 1
    <p id="testResult">Number of executed iterations: 1
    <p id="testResult">Number of failed iterations: 0
    <p id="testResult">Number of crashes: 0
    <p id="testResult">executeTestAsSubProcess: TestCase SmokeTst_PwrOn_ATCmd:myDUT ... Completed
    <p>&nbsp
    <p>***************************************************************************************
    <p>Python Test Automation - myDUT : 3G_C14_DL_UDP_2min_PwrSaveEna --> my Test Deecription
    <p>Testcase start: - 02/18/14 07:21:27
    <p>***************************************************************************************
    <p>&nbsp
    <p>**************************************************************************
    <p>*****  tcID: 3G_C14_DL_UDP_2min_PwrSaveEna  -  ueID: myDUT  *****
    <p>**************************************************************************
    <p>Test Case start: 02/18/14 07:22:02
    <p>*** Iteration 1  - 02/18/14 07:22:44 ***
    <p id="pass">Iteration 1: PASS
    <p id="iterResult">DL throughput: xxxxx.00 kbps
    <p id="iterResult">DL PHY throughput: xxxxx.00 kbps
    <p>&nbsp
    <p>*** Iteration 2  - 02/18/14 07:25:46 ***
    <p id="pass">Iteration 2: PASS
    <p id="iterResult">DL throughput: xxxxx.00 kbps
    <p id="iterResult">DL PHY throughput: xxxxx.00 kbps
    <p>&nbsp
    <p>*** Iteration 3  - 02/18/14 07:28:54 ***
```

In the example above the tests are still in progress, there may be 5, 10, or more, iterations to perform, and as you can see the file could become quite long. I would like the final line (`*** Iteration 3 ...` in this case) to be displayed on the screen

Ideally, anything to force the page to display at the end would have to be between the `<head> </head>` tags, since this is the only "properly formed" HTML

This system runs on a windows platform, although I am trying (where feasible) to remain platform independent

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

+++ Update +++

There are 3 log files produced by the logging class.  Where the code would be : `self.log.Verdict('*** Iteration %d  - %s ***' %(iterCounter, self.tNow()))` the output would go to 3 files with differing formats:

detailed.txt:

```
    2014-02-18 07:22:44,878 - MY_LOGGER - MY_VERDICT - *** Iteration 1  - 02/18/14 07:22:44 ***
```

verdict.txt:

```
    *** Iteration 1  - 02/18/14 07:22:44 ***
```

verdict.html:

```
    <p>*** Iteration 1  - 02/18/14 07:22:44 ***
```

Comment: Have you though about using a templating language like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/)? This way you could decouple data display logic from the data store (your text file).

Comment: I hadn't but I'll look at it .. thanks

The reason I am writing an HTML file is so that users submitting tests can see the results in real-time in their browser by accessing a file on a network share. Sadly there is no Webserver allowed on the network, so it has to be raw HTML.

Comment: Jinja2 is a good fit, it will produce raw html. You will have a lot more control on how the data is displayed.

Comment: @msvalkon ... from a quick read, Jinja2 would be doing the same job as the logging Filter. The code sends an output string (with or without parameters) to the log object, which writes it out to (in my case) up to 3 separate logs, only 1 of which is the HTML file. The HTML tagging, and styling is done by the logging filter applied to the log handler. The issue I'm having is ensuring that the HTML file displays the latest lines rather than the top of the log.

Comment: Yes the Filter can do that, but with Jinja or some other templating language, you would be easily able to control *where* on the page the data is displayed. For instance showing the test iterations with the latest as first, you would simply iterate the `Iterations` in reverse. Just food for thought. I'm not sure if the logging module is capable of rearranging the logged information in a way you want.

Comment: It would be too resource intensive to rewrite the entire log each time a record is added. For small logs it may be feasible, but as they grow it wouldn't work. The HTML log would need to insert the records at the top, and I'm fairly certain that I agree with you that it is beyond the capability of the logging module.

Comment: You could always just include a `<script>` tag inside the `<head>`, with some JS that either appends a `bottom` anchor child to the end of the `document` and jumps there, or, more hackily but maybe more simply, just does a `scrollBy`. You can do this in a `window.onLoad` handler, although some browsers may run it twice (once at the end of the file, and once again after some timeout-waiting-for-`</html>` expires), so you may want to add code to make sure it only runs once. But otherwise, it's dead simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally, anything to force the page to display at the end would have to be between the `<head>` `</head>` tags, since this is the only "properly formed" HTML.

Well, one of the things that legally can go in a `head` is a `script`.

And inside a `script` tag, you can write JavaScript that manipulates the page DOM, or the window object.

At this point, this becomes more of a JavaScript question than a Python, HTML, or CSS question, and I'm not sure what the "clean" way to do this is, but there are a number of options.

---

First, you can create that desired but missing `#bottom` anchor like this:

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute('id', 'bottom');
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
```

Technically, since you have no `<body>` tag, you can't really access `document.body`. Then again, since you have no `<body>` tag, the browser shouldn't be displaying your document in the first case. Practically, every browser will have a `body` element which includes everything after the `</head>`, so this will work.

---

Alternatively, you could forget about that tag, and just use any of various methods to jump to the end of the page instead of jumping to an anchor. For example, if your CSS isn't disabling the scrollbar or anything like that, you can just do:

```
window.scrollBy(0, 1000000);
```

---

Meanwhile, you don't want this code to run until the end of the page. But there *is* no end of the page, because no such thing exists until the `</html>` is parsed, and there is no `</html>`.

Practically, if you create a `window.onload` function in a local file, it will get run at the actual end of the file, which is exactly what you want. However, it may *also* get run a second time N seconds later (where N is some browser-specific or configuration timeout before giving up on an HTML page ever finishing)—even on a local `file:` URL where there's obviously no need for such a thing. So, you'll want some persistent flag to make sure you only run once. Or, alternatively, you can just have the `onload` function delete itself at the end.

---

I took your example HTML, added a few hundred more random `<p>` elements so it wouldn't fit on the screen, then added this right before `</head>`, to test the behavior on different browsers:

```
<script>
    window.ranOnLoadOnce = false;
    window.onload = function() {
        if (!window.ranOnLoadOnce) {
            var anchor = document.createElement('a');
            anchor.setAttribute('id', 'bottom')
            document.body.appendChild(anchor);
            window.scrollBy(0, 1000000);
            window.ranOnLoadOnce = true;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Safari, Chrome, and Firefox all immediately scrolled to the last page, and also ended up with a navigable `#bottom` anchor that I could have used. So, either mechanism seems to work as expected—but you'll probably want to test with at least IE.

Meanwhile, if I commented out the `ranOnLoadOnce` lines, Safari scrolled to the end again 120 seconds later, and Chrome did so every 120 seconds, while Firefox didn't. So, you apparently do need the protection on at least some major browsers, so you'd better include it or something similar.

Comment: Fantastic! .. thank you!

This works perfectly on IE (came up with an ActiveX warning, but when enabled it was precisely what I needed)

Comment: @NickHolt: Seriously, an ActiveX warning for running embedded JavaScript that does nothing but scroll the window and/or modify the DOM? Crazy…  But as long as it works, no need to debug it. :)